# Table Structure Php Matrix Grid

Tags: php, html

I would like to create a matrix grid using widths and drops from the database.
The price would need to be displayed in the associated width and drop cell.

For example:

```
width x drop:  600 700 800 900   
         600   226
         700       236
         800   248
         900           290
```

Some values will be not be there as the product instance has not been created.

I have three tables:

```
 1) product_instance (id, product_name, width_id, drop_id, price)
 2) product_width (id, width)
 3) product drop (id, drop)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>w x d</th>

        <?
         $query = "SELECT * FROM product_instance
                INNER JOIN product_width ON product_instance.width_id 
                = product_width.width_id 
                INNER JOIN product_drop ON product_instance.drop_id = 
                product_drop.drop_id
                INNER JOIN products ON product_instance.product_id = 
                products.product_id WHERE product_instance.product_id 
                = 1";

       $select_products = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_products)) {
          $width_value = $row['width_value'];
            echo "<th>$width_value</th>";
          }
         ?>
         </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>

         <?

          $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM product_instance
                   INNER JOIN product_width ON 
                    product_instance.width_id 
                   = product_width.width_id 
                INNER JOIN product_drop ON product_instance.drop_id = 
               product_drop.drop_id
                INNER JOIN products ON product_instance.product_id = 
                products.product_id WHERE product_instance.product_id 
                = 1";

             $select_products = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_products)) {

               $drop_value = $row['drop_value'];
                 $price = $row['price'];

                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>$drop_value</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$price</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                ?>


 </tbody>
 </table>
```

I'm not sure how to do this and have looked around but cant find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a workable solution using [PHPivot](https://github.com/mhadjimichael/PHPivot)

My code now looks like this:

```
<?php

 require 'pivot/PHPivot.php';

//Get the data
//Could be from a database, JSON, etc

 $query = "SELECT * FROM product_instance
           INNER JOIN product_width ON product_instance.width_id = 
           product_width.width_id 
           INNER JOIN product_drop ON product_instance.drop_id = 
           product_drop.drop_id
           INNER JOIN products ON product_instance.product_id = 
            products.product_id WHERE product_instance.product_id = 1";

         $select_products = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                            $result = [];
                            $counter = 0;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_products)) {

               $menu[$counter] = array(
               "width" => $row['width_value'],
               "price" => $row['price'],
                "drop" => $row['drop_value']
               );
              array_push($result,$menu[$counter]);
              $counter ++;
             }


$data = $result;
//Just needs to be saved in an associative PHP array   

$products = PHPivot::create($data)
             ->setPivotRowFields('width')
             ->setPivotColumnFields('drop')                                  
             ->setPivotValueFields('price',PHPivot::PIVOT_VALUE_SUM, 
             PHPivot::DISPLAY_AS_VALUE, 'Drop')
             ->addFilter('width', '', PHPivot::COMPARE_NOT_EQUAL)
             //Filter out blanks/unknown genre
             ->generate();

 echo $products->toHtml();

?>
```